# How can I use np,load() with tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to load numpy file with tensor. So, I use the tf.py_func(), but It occurs the TypeErrror. Can Numpy handle the Tensorflow tensor?

```py
def npload(array):
    return np.load(array)

output = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_list_LR_tensor, image_list_HR_tensor], shuffle=False, capacity=FLAGS.name_queue_capacity) 
# image_list_LR_tensor : a tensor, list of npy files

 # Reading and decode the images
reader = tf.WholeFileReader(name='image_reader')
image_LR = tf.read_file(output[0])

input_image_LR = tf.py_func(npload, [image_LR], [tf.float32])
input_image_LR = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(input_image_LR, dtype=tf.float32)
```

```py
# When use tf.py_func()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
         [[{{node load_image/PyFunc_1}}]]

# When use tf.py_fuction()
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
         [[{{node load_image/EagerPyFunc}}]]
```

Comment: `np.load` loads a file created with `np.save`, and usually tagged as `npy`.  The result will be a `ndarray`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! In the code above, [image_list_LR_tensor] is a variable that replaces the list of npy files  with a tensor. I modified the deep running code, and in the original code it converted the png file list to a tensor format and uploaded the png file with tf.decode_png (). Is there any way I can fix this by uploading npy file?